# Getting Threaddump java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor) at org.hsqldb.Session.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, garbage-collection

We are using a Struts2 application with my SQL database.
From a few months, we are getting Java Thread dumps and the application stops responding.

The thread dumps are as following :
"http-0.0.0.0-8443-98" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000043229000 nid=0x54be waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f8b3b8b0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)

"http-0.0.0.0-8443-179" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f8b3015c000 nid=0x571f waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f8b2faf9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.recycleWorkerThread(JIoEndpoint.java:724)

"http-0.0.0.0-8443-175" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f8b30163800 nid=0x5713 in Object.wait() [0x00007f8b3443b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)

"Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@2d2fa195" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005a06b800 nid=0x5631 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f8b34c4b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)

"http-0.0.0.0-8443-127" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000005c334800 nid=0x54e0 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f8b37c76000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)

"DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3" prio=10 tid=0x00007f8b714d4000 nid=0x5ac6 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f8bed917000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.octopus.scheduler.tasks.SyncCertificateActivationThreads.activate(SyncCertificateActivationThreads.java:62)

For Database, we are using

```
public class ConnectionManager {

/* Object stores the value of lock */
private static final Object lock = new Object();

/**
 * This method is used to get connection object holding the connection with
 * the database. This connection object is created using
 * 
 * @return Connection
 */
public Connection getDBConnection() {

    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();

        IEntityManager manager = new EntityManager();

        String dataSource = manager.getDatsourceInstance(application,
                coreProduct);
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("java:"
                + dataSource);

        if (ds != null) {
            conn = ds.getConnection();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return conn;
}

/**
 * This method is use to generate the random id.
 * 
 * @return
 */
public String generateId() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 13);
}

/**
 * This method is use to generate the id which contains the current system
 * time.
 * 

 */
public synchronized String generateNewId() {
    String id = "";
    synchronized (lock) {
        // id = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        id = String.valueOf(System.nanoTime());
    }
    return id;
}
```

What parameters, Standards, configurations are required to reduce such dumps as because of these applications stop performing.

Comment: Also we are using ParallelGC Strategy

Comment: Note that just because you’re placing `System.nanoTime()` within a `synchronized` does *not* guaranty that the next execution will read a different value. It may still happen within the granularity of the timer. Besides that, what you’ve posted, is not very helpful as this code is not directly involved in the posted stack traces (or is in the parts you cut off). It looks like a deadlock, but you didn’t include the part where the owned monitors are shown.